# sesman-Xvnc doesn't connect over xrdp

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

i'm trying to enable remote desktop on my xubuntu machine with xrdp.

I am on a (pretty much) vanilla xubuntu install. I installed xrdp with apt-get.

My xrdp config looks like this:

```
[xrdp1]
name=sesman-Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
```

`netstat -ato` shows that something is listening on port 3350 at least:

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:3350          *:*                     LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
```

I am able to connect over port 3389 to the xrdp screen, where I choose the sesman-Xvnc option, and enter my username and password. The Connection Log window then comes up saying

```
connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
```

Then it sits there forever. I am able to click the OK button and exit at any time.

Why doesn't it connect?

Comment: From where are you trying to connect? are you tunnelling port 3350 to port 3350 of your localhost? if so, please [edit] your question to include details

Comment: @steeldriver edited

Comment: Was this resolved? How'd you fix it?

Comment: @AnonymousPerson it was never resolved :( i still havent got it to work.

Comment: My exact same problem!

Comment: @AnonymousPerson if you figure it out, let me know by posting an answer!

Comment: @AnonymousPerson I just figured this out, while troubleshooting my bind configuration :P see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh. Somehow, I never realised that localhost wasn't immune to the firewall.

I added an iptables rule for the localhost interface, and now it works.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --destination-ports 3350 -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

In the future I'll use this rule to make sure all localhost traffic is allowed:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: exactly my problem. not sure how iptables is connected but it worked.

Comment: Remember to change `ip6tables` rules if you are using RDP from an ipv6 address (which my Win 10 box decided to use). My default drop policy ended up biting me with this. Also don't forget `iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4` and `ip6tables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6`

Answer (score 1):

These two steps will sort out your issue:

```
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
```